# Kotlin coroutines. Kotlin Flow and shared preferences. awaitClose is never called

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'd love to observe changes of a shared preference. Here is how I Use Kotlin Flow to do it:

**Data source.**

```
interface DataSource {

    fun bestTime(): Flow<Long>

    fun setBestTime(time: Long)
}

class LocalDataSource @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext context: Context
) : DataSource {

    private val preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun bestTime() = callbackFlow {
        trySendBlocking(preferences, PREF_KEY_BEST_TIME)
        val listener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
            if (key == PREF_KEY_BEST_TIME) {
                trySendBlocking(sharedPreferences, key)
            }
        }
        preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
        awaitClose { // NEVER CALLED
            preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private fun ProducerScope<Long>.trySendBlocking(
        sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
        key: String?
    ) {
        trySendBlocking(sharedPreferences.getLong(key, 0L))
            .onSuccess { }
            .onFailure {
                Log.e(TAG, "", it)
            }
    }

    override fun setBestTime(time: Long) = preferences.edit {
        putLong(PREF_KEY_BEST_TIME, time)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LocalDataSource"

        private const val PREFS_FILE_NAME = "PREFS_FILE_NAME"
        private const val PREF_KEY_BEST_TIME = "PREF_KEY_BEST_TIME"
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
interface Repository {

    fun observeBestTime(): Flow<Long>

    fun setBestTime(bestTime: Long)
}

class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val dataSource: DataSource
) : Repository {

    override fun observeBestTime() = dataSource.bestTime()

    override fun setBestTime(bestTime: Long) = dataSource.setBestTime(bestTime)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class BestTimeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {

    // Backing property to avoid state updates from other classes
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(0L)
    val uiState: StateFlow<Long> = _uiState

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.observeBestTime()
                .onCompletion { // CALLED WHEN THE SCREEN IS ROTATED OR HOME BUTTON PRESSED
                    Log.d("myTag", "viewModelScope onCompletion")
                }
                .collect { bestTime ->
                    _uiState.value = bestTime
                }
        }
    }

    fun setBestTime(time: Long) = repository.setBestTime(time)
}
```

**Fragment.**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MetaDataFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_meta_data) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var timeFormatter: TimeFormatter

    @Inject
    lateinit var bestTimeViewModel: BestTimeViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val bestTimeView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.best_time_value)

        // Create a new coroutine in the lifecycleScope
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            // repeatOnLifecycle launches the block in a new coroutine every time the
            // lifecycle is in the STARTED state (or above) and cancels it when it's STOPPED.
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                // Trigger the flow and start listening for values.
                // This happens when lifecycle is STARTED and stops
                // collecting when the lifecycle is STOPPED
                bestTimeViewModel.uiState
                    .map { millis ->
                        timeFormatter.format(millis)
                    }
                    .onCompletion { // CALLED WHEN THE SCREEN IS ROTATED OR HOME BUTTON PRESSED
                        Log.d("MyApp", "onCompletion")
                    }
                    .collect {
                        bestTimeView.text = it
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed that `awaitClose` is never called. But this is where my clean-up code is. Please advise. If it's not a good idea to use `callbackFlow` in the first place, please let me know (as you can see some functions are `ExperimentalCoroutinesApi` meaning their behaviour can change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that allows me to save a simple dataset such as a preference and observe its changes using Kotlin Flow. It's `Preferences DataStore`.
This is the code lab and guide I used:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#0
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore

and this is my code:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.emptyPreferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.longPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import java.io.IOException

data class UserPreferences(val bestTime: Long)

private const val USER_PREFERENCES_NAME = "user_preferences"

private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(
    name = USER_PREFERENCES_NAME
)

interface DataSource {

    fun userPreferencesFlow(): Flow<UserPreferences>

    suspend fun updateBestTime(newBestTime: Long)
}

class LocalDataSource(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) : DataSource {

    override fun userPreferencesFlow(): Flow<UserPreferences> =
        context.dataStore.data
            .catch { exception ->
                // dataStore.data throws an IOException when an error is encountered when reading data
                if (exception is IOException) {
                    emit(emptyPreferences())
                } else {
                    throw exception
                }
            }
            .map { preferences ->
                val bestTime = preferences[PreferencesKeys.BEST_TIME] ?: 0L
                UserPreferences(bestTime)
            }

    override suspend fun updateBestTime(newBestTime: Long) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.BEST_TIME] = newBestTime
        }
    }
}

private object PreferencesKeys {
    val BEST_TIME = longPreferencesKey("BEST_TIME")
}
```

and the dependency to add to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Thats good as long as you dont need to encrypt your data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are injecting your ViewModel as if it was just a regular class, by using

```
@Inject
lateinit var bestTimeViewModel: BestTimeViewModel
```

Because of this, the ViewModel's `viewModelScope` is never cancelled, and therefor the Flow is collected forever.

Per [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels), you should use

```
privat val bestTimeViewModel: BestTimeViewModel by viewModels()
```

This ensures that the ViewModel's `onCleared` method, which in turn will cancel the `viewModelScope`, is called when your Fragment is destroyed.

Also make sure your ViewModel is annotated with `@HiltViewModel`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class BestTimeViewModel @Inject constructor(...) : ViewModel()
```

Comment: thank you for the `HiltViewModel` suggestion. But `awaitClose` is still not called. I think I understand why. It's not that `awaitClose` is called when the coroutines is cancelled. It's the callback's responsibility to provide `onCancel` and trigger cancellation there. The multi-shot callback section https://elizarov.medium.com/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf -